# Round decimal numbers and compare up to 3 decimal places in java

Tags: java

I am having problem with comparing two double numbers up to 3 decimal places. When I try to round 3.1756, I always get 3.176 the last number changes due to 6 last number. Please, help me to get exact number (3.175) from whole decimal numbers.

Comment: double? Must read good article about floating point. Genrally known is limit of accuracy, but not knowt "representation problem". For strict application use BigDecimal

Comment: Make up your mind. Your title says ';decimal numbers' but your question says 'double numbers'. They aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

```
 BigDecimal d=new BigDecimal("3.1756").setScale(3,RoundingMode.DOWN);
```